# Matlab: How do I disable a pop-up command window error when I run the compiled exe?

Tags: matlab

I want to avoid an alert to pop-up when I run a compiled program in a batch scheduled environment. This because it would remain unnoticed and therefore the execution would not exit with an error code, but just hang. I'm not there to press the OK button. Any ideas? 
Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise the `isdeployed` flag:

```
if isdeployed
  %hardcode something
else
  %show your popup
end
```